# How to prove this involving sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider an example of a sequence,
$$\frac{1}{1},\frac{2}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{5},\frac{5}{6}.$$
that is, a sequence where the denominators always increase by 1, each consecutive term, and where the numerators also increase by one but not necessarily each consecutive term.

Suppose that I denote this **kind** of sequence in general as $\left(\frac{a_i}{i}\right)_{i=1}^{n}$, where the first term of the sequence $a_1$ is either $1$ or $0$. Now, given that the last term of the sequence, $a_n/n > 0.8$ and that at some point in the sequence, say, $a_j/j< 0.8$ (with $j<n$). Does this imply that there is always a term in the sequence, say $a_k/k$ with $j<k<n$ such that $a_k/k = 0.8$?

Simple examples show that this is indeed true. However, I can not give a formal proof.

Thanks!

Comment: Should the last term be $\frac 46$?

Comment: I edit my post. I should have said, *this kind of sequences*. The sequence in my post is just an example of a general type of sequences.

Comment: Hint:  a simpler problem is to prove that the fraction must be $\frac 12$ at some point (just look at the first time it crosses that level).  Indeed, it is generally true that you must hit every fraction of the form $\frac {k}{k+1}$ (assuming that at some point you are below it and at another you are above it).

Comment: @Siron Yeah, but that sequence is *not* an example of that general type of sequence *unless* you make  the denominator of the last fraction one more than the denominator of the penultimate fraction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have $\frac{a_n}n>\frac45 >\frac{a_j}j$ with $n>j$. That is, $5a_n>4n$ and $5a_j<4j$. Let $b_k=5a_k-4k$. As $a_{k+1}$ is either $a_k$ or $a_k+1$, we have $$b_{k+1}=5a_{k+1}-4k-4=\begin{cases}5a_k-4k-4&=b_k-4\quad \text{ or}\\5(a_k+1)-4k-4&=b_k+1\end{cases}$$
Thus if the integer $b_k$ increases, it only increases in steps of $1$. From $b_j<0<b_n$ we see that there must be a *first* index $k$ between $j$ and $n$ for which $b_k\ge 0$. Then $b_k\le b_{k-1}+1$ and $b_{k-1}<0$, hence $b_k=0$ as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose all the terms are below $\frac 45$ up until $\frac AN$ and that the next one is strictly greater than $\frac 45$.  We will derive a contradiction.

Then we have $$\frac AN<\frac 45\implies 5A<4N\implies 5A≤4N-1$$  Where the last inequality follows from its predecessor since both sides are integers.

Of course the next fraction must be $\frac {A+1}{N+1}$ (we know the denominator goes up by one, and if the numerator didn't increase then the fraction would decrease).  We get $$\frac {A+1}{N+1}>\frac 45\implies 5A+5>4N+4\implies 5A>4N-1$$  a contradiction, proving the desired claim.